# Single quote in tsx file with prettier

Tags: reactjs, typescript, prettier

For 2-3 weeks, while I didn't change anything in prettier file, VSC started changing single quotes to double quotes, while it was always single quotes. I tried many options but it keeps changing it. Heres my .prettierrc

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "printWidth": 200,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "quoteProps": "as-needed"
}
```

EDIT: I think, that it is a matter of .tsx files, as prettier has just option for .jsx files but still didn't find a solution.

Comment: Not really a solution. I was using prettier in the beginning but found it had a lot of quirks with VSCode. I switched to eslint, which works much better.

Comment: I have tslint in my project (as it is written in typescript) but when I want to format according to tslint config it doesn't follow those rules from there.

Comment: I think this is your problem.  You have more than one tool trying to apply rules. I think you should remove one of them, preferable prettier. And then try to configure the remaining properly.

Comment: But tslint will just show error in terminal, just prettier formats files and for now there is just problem with quoting in components files (.tsx)

Comment: I can see you have "jsxSingleQuote": true, . this should solve the problem as long as you are using the latest prettier. I had the same problem but after adding that all the double quotes in my jsx files were turned to double single quotes

Answer (score 46):

In `.prettierrc`, add:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true,
  "jsxSingleQuote": true
}
```

Comment: This works in `.tsx` too. Thanks!

Comment: `jsxSingleQuote` did it for me as with `singleQuote` only it didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: It's good that there are two separate options. `jsxSingleQuote` works.

Answer (score 3):

create a `.prettierrc` file on your root folder and add:

```
{
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue for a few days. I checked all the settings and they seem to be fine.

At the moment THE ONLY thing that helps is downgrading down to the previous version  of Prettier in my case it was version 2.3.0 (I didn't check all the versions between this and the latest but few of them had the same issue)

Comment: you mean version of Prettier?

Comment: Yes, the version of Prettier

Answer (score 1):

add `tsxSingleQuote: true,` in prettierrc.js file

Answer (score 0):

On your User Settings make sure you have the following line:

```
"prettier.singleQuote": true
```

You can access the user settings by `CTRL+,` on windows or `CMD+,` on mac.

If you're using the settings GUI just search for `single quote` and check/uncheck the `Prettier: Jsx Single quote` and `Prettier: Single quote`

Comment: I have it all set like you mentioned but is still changes it to double quotes in my .tsx files

Answer (score 0):

Best place to read up on this configuration is the website.
https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html

If you are using a package.json, create a new key if you dont have a "prettier" key.

```
"prettier":{
    "singleQuote": true
}
```

Or you could create a `.prettierrc` file written in JSON and add the same key pair value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.prettierrc.json` file in the root folder of your project, and set the `"singleQuote": true` key.

*(This configuration has been tested with Reactjs + TypeScript.)*

```
{
  "trailingComma": "es5",
  "tabWidth": 4,
  "semi": false,
  "singleQuote": true
}
```

For more detailed information, please refer to the official documentation at:
https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html